# network connection error in creating sql database from App-Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a MVC 5 application. In my MVC 5 application i want to create a mdf file from App-Data folder but when i want to add mdf file from Add New Item menu of Add_Data folder, i receive an error

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to      SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 – Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details`

Comment: So did you see the event log? What does it say?

Comment: @Nilesh Event Viewer shows this `LocalDB instance is corrupted. See the Windows Application event log for error details.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running

```
SqlLocalDB delete “v11.0”
```

followed by

```
SqlLocalDB create “v11.0”
```

SqlLocalDB.exe is located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn`.